# Have cancer rates increased for a given age?

Tags: cancer, middle-aged-adults, young-adults

If I search the internet for articles about the increase or decrease of cancer rates, I find ones that say that cancer rates are increasing, but this is generally due to people living longer. Obviously cancer rates increase as you get older and if you don't die from anything else cancer will eventually get you in the end. Some articles also talk about some kinds of cancer decreasing because the known causes of them are decreasing (ie. smoking -> lung cancer).

I would like to know if there are any studies out there which have looked at the change in cancer rates for specific ages or age ranges. For example, have general cancer rates increased for people in their 50s in the last few decades, worldwide, or in North America, or whatever?

More specific breakdowns by type of cancer and gender and region etc. is also handy but I really just want to answer the question of whether people in developed countries have an increasing or decreasing risk of getting cancer apart from the aging population factor.